# Production ready version of apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I currently have a production cassandra cluster running on apache cassandra version 3.9. However I have hit a bug that prevents me from being able to bootsrap new nodes. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12813. This issue is fixed as of version 3.11. Given I am going to have to upgrade, I'd like to know the best production ready version that I should adopt as of the present.

Answer (score 3):

If your on 3.9 you should go to the latest 3.11 build (3.11.2 to date). Its all bug fixes between 3.9 and it, some of which are serious so you should upgrade.